# Accessing a list in a defquery

Tags: clojure, anglican

This may be a pretty basic question but I could not find answer elsewhere. 
I have a list that contains only numbers.

```
(def data [1 2.3 4.3 5.6 5.3 2.4])
```

I write the following defquery to uniformly sample from this list `data`

```
(defquery pois [data1]
  (let [days (sample 
              (uniform-discrete 1 6))          
    day1 ((nth data1 days))
      ]
    day1))
```

and try to get samples using

```
(def samples 
  (take 100
        (doquery :importance pois [data])))

(first samples)
```

I tried passing data to the defquery pois but still no luck. Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `defquery` and `doquery`?

Comment: Sorry.. I should have made it clear. I am working with Anglican, a probabilistic programming language based on Clojure.

Comment: What do you expect the end result to look like?

Comment: Honestly, you'll probably have better luck on [their slack](https://clojurians.slack.com/?redir=%2Fmessages%2Fanglican%2F) than here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that this may not be the right platform for this but nevertheless for clojing this question..here how I was able to solve it.

```
(defquery pois [data1]
  (let [days (sample 
              (uniform-discrete 1 6))          
    day1 ((nth data1 days))
      ]
    day1))

(def samples 
  (take 10000
        (doquery :importance pois [data])))

(first samples)
```